# Transfering Odds Ratios to another SNP with high LD?

Tags: genetics, statistics

I have the Odds Ratios (OR) for a particular risk allele in a SNP (I'll call it SNP1).  That SNP was unfortunately not genotyped in my data, but I don't want to throw it away.  I have looked up the SNP on LDLink and another SNP (I'll call it SNP2) is in high linkage disequilibrium with SNP1 (R2=0.94).

How do I transfer the OR from the SNP1 allele to the corresponding SNP2 allele?

I know it is something similar to log(OR)*sqrt(R2) but I'm not entirely sure.  Could somone please clarify if this is the correct formula?